# SKPhysics didBeginContact() not working with basic game

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have built a game that relies on SKPhysics to detect a collision between the player and randomly generated walls. For some reason, SKPhysics didBeginContact() is not working. I have added a print statement into it, however it does not run at all. I have added the physics to the wall class and the player class, but the result is the same. If you notice anything that jumps out at you, please let me know. 
Code:
GameScene.swift

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  marioRunner
//
//  Created by nick on 11/18/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var movingGround: MLMovingGround!
    var hero: MLHero!
    var wallGenerator: MLWallGenerator!
    var isStarted = false

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.5, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        movingGround = MLMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 20))
        movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)
        addChild(movingGround)

        self.hero = MLHero()
        hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(hero)

        wallGenerator = MLWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
        wallGenerator.position = view.center
        addChild(wallGenerator)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    func start() {
        isStarted = true
        movingGround.start()
        wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(1)
        hero.flip()
    }

    func gameOver() {
        hero.stop()
    }


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        //gameOver()
        hero.body.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
        print("HIT")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if isStarted == false{
            start()
        } else {
            hero.flip()
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

Wall Class

```
//
//  MLWall.swift
//  marioRunner
//
//  Created by nick on 12/9/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MLWall: SKSpriteNode {

    let WALL_WIDTH: CGFloat = 30.0
    let WALL_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50.0
    let WALL_COLOR = UIColor.blackColor()

    init() {
        let size = CGSizeMake(WALL_WIDTH, WALL_HEIGHT)
        super.init(texture: nil, color: WALL_COLOR, size: size)
        loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size)
        startMoving()
    }

    func loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: CGSize) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCategory
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    func startMoving() {
        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y:0, duration:1)
        runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
    }
}
```

Hero class

```
//
//  MLHero.swift
//  marioRunner
//
//  Created by nick on 12/7/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MLHero: SKSpriteNode {
    var body: SKSpriteNode!
    var arm: SKSpriteNode!
    var leftFoot: SKSpriteNode!
    var rightFoot: SKSpriteNode!
    var isUpsideDown = false
    init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 44))
        loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size)
        body = SKSpriteNode(color:UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 40))
        body.position = CGPointMake(0, 2)
        addChild(body)
        let skinColor = UIColor(red:207.0/255.0, green:193.0/255.0, blue: 168.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let face = SKSpriteNode(color: skinColor, size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 2))
        face.position = CGPointMake(0, 6)
        body.addChild(face)
        let eyeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let leftEye = SKSpriteNode(color: eyeColor, size: CGSizeMake(6,6))
        let rightEye = leftEye.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        let pupil = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(3,3))
        pupil.position = CGPointMake(2, 0)
        leftEye.addChild(pupil)
        rightEye.addChild(pupil.copy() as! SKSpriteNode)
        leftEye.position = CGPointMake(-4, 0)
        face.addChild(leftEye)
        rightEye.position = CGPointMake(14, 0)
        face.addChild(rightEye)
    }
    /*func performOneRunCycle() {
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 2, duration: 0.05)
        let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -2, duration: 0.05)
    }*/

    func loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: CGSize) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    }

    func flip() {
        isUpsideDown = !isUpsideDown
        var scale: CGFloat
        if isUpsideDown {
            scale = -1.0
        } else {
           scale = 1.0
        }
        let translate = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: scale*(size.height + kMLGroundHeight), duration: 0.1)
        let flip = SKAction.scaleYTo(scale, duration: 0.1)

        runAction(translate)
        runAction(flip)
    }

    func stop() {
        //body.removeAllActions()
        print("stopped")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Constants.swift

```
//
//  constants.swift
//  marioRunner
//
//  Created by nick on 12/10/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

let kMLGroundHeight: CGFloat = 20.0
let kdefaultXToMovePerSecond: CGFloat = 320.0
let heroCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let wallCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
```

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Please show us the category constants

Comment: @user3351949 Added. Thank you for the help

Comment: Interesting... maybe you should try to add a contactTestBitMask  to a wall node :-/

Comment: Also you can assign a `collsionBitmask` for both of them